# How to find objects by key in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Say I have the following object in my redux state:

```
books : {
    1 : {
        id : 1,
        authorId : 5,
        bookId : 22
    },
    2 : {
        id : 2,
        authorId : 5,
        bookId : 15,
    },
    3 : {
        id : 3,
        authorId : 42,
        bookId : 12
    }
},
```

how would I know find & access book number 2? I know that in arrays I would simply do `books[1]`, but how can I access the object if the parent structure is a javascript object?

Comment: Did you try `books[1]` with what you have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access an element in an array with an index starting from `0`, like you noted.

Accessing a key in an object is just a matter of using the key name:

```
const secondBook = books[2];
```